# Do we need more than one Pager(viewpager) class, if we want to add tabs in more than one activity?

Tags: java, android, tabs

I have to make project which consist of 3 Activities. 1st and 2nd activity consist of 2 Tabs while 3rd activity needs 3 tabs. Do i need to make 3 Pager clases for each activity? Or if One Pager.class can handle all tabs then how we can sequence it?? 
Thanks to all In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use same `PagerAdapter` class. Below is an sample `PagerAdapter`.

**TabsPagerAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**From your `FirstActivity.java`:**

```
TabLayout mTabLayout;
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsPagerAdapte mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    // Tab layout
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    // View pager
    mViewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    // Adapter
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // 2 Tabs
    mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
    mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentTwo(), "TWO");

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

**From your `SecondActivity.java`:**

```
TabLayout mTabLayout;
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsPagerAdapte mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    // Tab layout
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    // View pager
    mViewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    // Adapter
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // 2 Tabs
    mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
    mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentTwo(), "TWO");

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

**From your `ThirdActivity.java`:**

```
TabLayout mTabLayout;
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsPagerAdapte mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    // Tab layout
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    // View pager
    mViewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    // Adapter
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // 3 Tabs
    mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
    mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentTwo(), "TWO");
    mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentThree(), "THREE");

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: i am new at Android studio as i am junior! I want to know that where i have to add my fragments?? and how?? because your code is almost same as my code but i am trying to figure out that where to add fragments?? in "addFragment" Function??  of Pager class? if yes then how???

Comment: From your activity onCreate() method, you can add fragment to viewpager using adapter.addFrag() method >>>  // 2 Tabs
        mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
        mAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentTwo(), "TWO");         Please see my answer

Comment: Thankyou so much. This helps Alot!

Comment: My pleasure... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same class. Just make sure your overridden methods can differentiate which activity it is in. So `getCount()` in `FragmentPagerAdapter` as an example would return two in your 1st and 2nd activity, but three in your 3rd one. Same goes for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use this pageradapter class for each activity. it will create size that you want in a activity

```
public class ExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ExamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

   public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```